# Is there a way to disable only date in bootstrap datetimepicker 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I want to disable only date in my datetime field. But when i disable previous and future dates it disables time also. 
Time should be free to change.[image: My datetime control is here..]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is going to answer your question but, if you want to just pick time, you can do it like this:

Change your format to `HH:mm A`.

I've made a [sample](https://jsfiddle.net/gpjL1098/) for you.

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
   format: 'HH:mm A'
});
```

You can change it to whatever you want. Since it uses mooment.js you can use these [formatting options](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/).

Comment: You are right but in my case i don't have input type separate for time and date. it's one control as datetime. and i fixed that someway.

Comment: This is running on one field tho. I thought you just want time. What exactly it is that you are after? If its not sorted, i will try to help you.

Comment: thanks i have done that previous day. i had to disable the date except the one date so one cannot change the date but time should be free to change.